# Databases: Where does the data go before a commit?

Tags: database, ms-access

We're trying to locate a memory leak in our code.  As the software runs, I can see memory usage slowly get bigger and bigger.  Each operation add records in a database.

Then, I was wondering, where does the data from an INSERT command really go before we commit the changes?  Is the data added in the actual database file and flagged as "Rollback this if requested"? or only stored in internal memory and dumped when the commit request is done?

If it helps, we're using Access for now.

Comment: I much doubt the memory leak has anything to do with the transaction. The transaction is stored in a local table. However for regular edition of data with forms you are NOT USING access transactions and thus regular operation would not apply here.

Comment: No, no, I'm not asking for help regarding the memory leak and not considering the transaction as being the culprit.  I was only wondering where SQL commands (ie. INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, etc.) perform their action.

Answer (score 5):

As part of the "Begin Transaction", the "Data" as such does not go anywhere or change in any way, instead it records the list of commands issued to it.  If you then cancel the transaction with a "Rollback" the instructions are dropped and no changes made, else if a "Commit" is issued then it executes the saved instructions in the correct order.

As the instructions are stored in a local table (as mentioned by Albert) this is why you see a memory increase as the local file is opened in it's entirety to memory (hence why we split front and back end database's in Access to avoid dumping a huge file on the RAM)

Also worth mentioning that any SQL statements that are issued have their syntax checked before been saved in order to ensure that if you are running multiple SQL's; it won't fail mid way through and leave your data in a state that you did not intend.

Apologies for "Instructions" I know this is the layman's term but I hope it makes sense.